# An overly abstract question or simple idiocy, how does one prove that a probability measure sums to 1?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

The question of the topic might be absolutely idiotic or perhaps overly abstract.

I'm trying to figure out how one assures either via proof or reasoning that a probability measure sums to 1.

I know from various topics that some of the question presumably lies in measure theory and that of course it is a fundamental axiom of probability theory. But the presentation of the axiom in probability is done in some sense via set theory and that's where I forgot how the probability measure becomes 1 rather than using the lebesgue measure making it simply the "length" of the set.

I guess I'm asking if anyone knows or has the proof for the probability measure summing to 1 on a sigma-algebra.

Comment: Pretty sure itt is just a definition of a probability measure.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm also unsure as to whether one could make a rigourous argument for why a set with a probability measure could be proven to summarize to 1. But I guess it's an axiom entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the definition of probability measure. In any particular case, if you start with a measure you can try to prove its value is $1$ on the whole space, or normalize it to make that happen. So for Lebesgue measure on the interval $[0,2]$ you would multiply by $1/2$ to make the corresponding probability measure.

Comment: I oddly can't upvote your comment. But thanks. This makes a lot of sense

Comment: Of course, sometimes you can't normalize - when the measure is unbounded.